# Ethernet driver initialization fails in the STM32F217VGT6

Tags: error-handling, embedded, stm32, freertos, stm32cubeide

DETAILS: STM32CubeIDE v1.13.0

I created a project for the STM32F217VGT6 MCU with FreeRTOS as the middleware. The code generated in 'Src/main.c' has the following problem:

- The generated function 'MX_ETH_Init()' calls 'HAL_ETH_Init()'.  If 'HAL_ETH_Init()' returns status other than 'HAL_OK', 'MX_ETH_Init()' calls '_Error_Handler()', which (of course) does not return.

At the moment I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Use the debugger to step into HAL_ETH_Init() to learn why it's returning an error.